# Placing icon over tablayout

Tags: android

I am trying to place an icon to my tablayout. My tablayout have fixed 6 tabs. And my icon should place next to second tab icon. I tried following code and it worked well on simulator but not on real device.

My code:

**Tablayout.xml and icon**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#40436F"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_bar_bg"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="0dp"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMinWidth="58dp"
        app:tabGravity="center"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/notification_bg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/notification_bg"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView32"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

**And code:**

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    int marginDp=(pxToDp(tabLayout.getWidth()))/6*2;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)badgeView.getLayoutParams();
    relativeParams.setMargins(Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, marginDp, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())), Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 63, getResources().getDisplayMetrics())), 0, 0);  // left, top, right, bottom
    badgeView.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
}
```

**On simulator (This is what i want):**

[image]

**And this is on device (it is placing wrong)**

[image]

How can i fix this?

Also i don't know if this way is best to achive this thing. You can suggest me another way to do this thing. :)

Comment: Seems like `marginDp` calculation isn't correct w.r.t device density. Check it. Or alternatively you could use a negative margin for the red colored view in the layout (if suitable) or `translateX`/`translateY` attribute set to `dp` values. The last would prevent undesired behavior on different screen densities.

Comment: @Onik Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a custom view for your tabs, where you could specify a RelativeLayout containing your tab image, the red notification indicator, and a textview that you could use to set the number inside the notification indicator.  Here's one example of a way to use custom layouts for tabs: https://mobikul.com/make-custom-tabs-icons-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can have a horizontal linear layout with tab images acting as tab layout. You can handle each clicks of the added imageviews on their own by getting the viewpager's position or vice versa.
That way .. you get to design any tab layout you want.
Hope that helps